# hold CTRL+Double Left Click to open file location on shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey

I work with shortcuts of my files and folders very often. Currently we right click on a **Shortcut** and then look for `Open file location`and click on it So...
Do you know any method to achieve this easier/faster? For example, maybe with AutoHotKey ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to press the I key after right clicking on a shortcut.

Another way:

```
; In Explorer or Desktop, 
; hold down the LButton over a Shortcut, 
; press and release the Control key to open the file location:

#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ||  WinActive("Program Manager") 
; Explorer or Desktop

    ~LButton & Ctrl Up:: 
        Click right
        Send i
    Return

#If
```

Comment: Thank you, It did helped me a lot.